# Mapping auto.arima() to list of subset timeseries

Tags: r, forecasting, purrr, broom

I have a list of timeseries data like this:

```
> str(ffz2$time_series)
List of 89
 $ 1_1  : Time-Series [1:47] from 2013 to 2017: 6.95 7.03 7.06 7.03 7.09 ...
 $ 1_10 : Time-Series [1:47] from 2013 to 2017: 7.1 7.13 7.12 7.13 7.21 ...
 $ 1_2  : Time-Series [1:47] from 2013 to 2017: 7.28 7.31 7.3 7.32 7.35 ...
 $ 1_3  : Time-Series [1:47] from 2013 to 2017: 6.85 6.92 6.92 6.92 6.98 ...
```

When I map the auto.arima() function from the forecast package onto it it works fine.

```
ffz2_models <- ffz2 %>%
    mutate(
      model = time_series %>% map(auto.arima)
)
```

However if I perform a subsetting operation, either the map or the auto.arima function seems to stop working.

```
train <- dam_models$time_series %>%
    map(subset, end = 36)

> str(train)
List of 89
 $ 1_1  : Time-Series [1:36] from 2013 to 2016: 6.95 7.03 7.06 7.03 7.09 ...
 $ 1_10 : Time-Series [1:36] from 2013 to 2016: 7.1 7.13 7.12 7.13 7.21 ...
 $ 1_2  : Time-Series [1:36] from 2013 to 2016: 7.28 7.31 7.3 7.32 7.35 ...
 $ 1_3  : Time-Series [1:36] from 2013 to 2016: 6.85 6.92 6.92 6.92 6.98 ...
```

Then the map(auto.arima) returns this error:

```
> trainingmodels <- train %>%
+     map(auto.arima)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

Also, if I extract a single timeseries from the list and store it as a separate value, then perform the auto.arima on that value - it works!

```
> timeseries1_2 <- train$`1_2` 

> modeltimeseries1_2 <- auto.arima(timeseries1_2)  

> head(modeltimeseries1_2)
$coef
        ma1       drift 
-0.43701717  0.01173471 

$sigma2
[1] 0.0004384713

$var.coef
                 ma1           drift
ma1    0.02429125831 -0.000025689037
drift -0.00002568904  0.000003959022

$mask
[1] TRUE TRUE

$loglik
[1] 86.63868

$aic
[1] -167.2774
```

A workaround here is that I could extract each individual item in the list to its own value and run auto.arima on each one separately without the use of map() or lapply(), however I have 89 of them. So thats 89 sets of training data im trying to model, along with a further 89 test sets to be extracted (assuming I use this method) and forecasted.

Any help with mapping auto.arima to a subset of a timeseries is greatly appreciated!